# Adding GET parameter to url results in extra fields error

Tags: php, symfony

I keep getting the following output next to my form:

`This form should not contain extra fields.`

Note I do **not** have multiple submit buttons for the form. However, the page number anchor links to a URL that includes one additional `_GET` parameter for the page number, i.e `search?q=toys&page=2`.

I suspect this is the reason for the error, as the error does not appear on the first page of the results.

I was wondering what should I do to fix this problem, while keeping `csrf_protection` set to `false`?

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('', 'form', $search, array('csrf_protection' => false))
            ->setMethod('GET')
            ->add('q', 'text', array('label'=>false, 'required' =>false))
            ->add('search', 'submit')
            ->getForm();
```

I tried adding the following to the `createNamedBuilder()` array:

`'extra_fields_message' => false` , which gets rid of the error text but not the actual list (the bullet still appears).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not include 'page' in your form and default it to 1?

Comment: You would only need a hidden field if your form method would be POST. Currently it is GET. That's why Symfony assumes that every GET var belongs to the form. You could try to seperate them (via Form Types) or just add the 'page' var to your form via Form Factory.

Comment: Check out this [article in the Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes). It will teach you to create classes representing forms. In these classes you can define a form name and symfony will create 'namespaces' to seperate each form. I'm not sure if you can do that (or if you would want to) with the form factory. In general I personaly manage such simple tasks (1-2 form fields) without a form, because it's simply much easier and faster to do so.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. However, your method seems wayyy over complicated. All I'm trying to do is use one additional GET variable (than accounted for in the form builder) by passing it via the url to a controller. Any other suggestions?

Comment: As I said, I also find it a bit complicated for such a simple application. I've also only been working with symfony for a couple months now, so I'm not 100% sure what the best practice is. Currently I would suggest just getting the different variables from the URL without forms: `$this->getRequest()->query->get('q')` (in a controller).

Comment: @AnchovyLegend, trying to use `GET` to do something different than `GETing` data is actually "over complicated" (to quote you). Use `POST`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using it to get data, which is why I need to use GET.